# Get first letter of each word in string and concatenate into new word using Regex

Tags: regex, vb.net

I don't know how to get all of the first matched letters from a regex match concatenated. I am trying to expand my knowledge and use of regex.

The code I show below does exactly what I want to do, however I would like to be able to do the same thing using regex. The regex code that I have tried matches nicely the first letter of each word, one word at a time but I would like to get all of the first letters at once without looping.

```
If Not myString.Contains("/") And myString.ToUpper() = myString Then
    Dim words As String() = myString.Split(" "c)
    Dim initials As String = ""
    For Each Word As String In words
        initials &= Word(0)
    Next
    DGV1(1, i).Value = initials
End If
```

The regex that I have tried that does match one letter at a time: My string (myString) is like: DEL REY name CLUB

```
Dim initial As String = Regex.Match(myString, "\b[a-z][A-Z]")
```

From the sample regex code shown I would like to show the first letters DRnC in a DataGridView cell just like the non regex method shown above.

Comment: Try `Dim initials As String = Regex.Replace(text, "\W*(?:\b(\w)\w*|$)", "$1")`. To only match letters, use `"\P{L}*(?:(\p{L})\p{L}*|$)"`

Comment: Also, why not use  a more straight-forward `Dim results As String = String.Concat(Regex.Matches(myString, "\b\w").Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value).ToList())`?

Comment: Your recommendation to use replace is the cleanest for my application. It works like a charm. Thank your for your help. I have reduced my code by five lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach in my opinion is to find all first word letters and then concat the results:

```
Dim results As String = String.Concat(Regex.Matches(myString, "\b\p{L}").Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value).ToList())
```

Here, `\b\p{L}` finds all occurrences of any letter not preceded with a letter, digit or connector punctuation and some diacritic marks. `Regex.Matches` matches all occurrences there are in the string, then, `.Cast(Of Match)().Select(Function(m) m.Value).ToList()` extracts the match values into a list, and `String.Concat` joins them into a single string.

If you plan to use a single regex method call, you may consider `Regex.Replace`:

```
Dim results As String = Regex.Replace(text, "\P{L}*(?:(\p{L})\p{L}*|$)", "$1")
```

Here, `\P{L}*(?:(\p{L})\p{L}*|$)` matches any 0+ chars other than letters, then it matches and captures into Group 1 any letter and then matches any 0+ letters, or matches the end of string. The `$1` replacement restores the first word letter in the result.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CP%7BL%7D*%28%3F%3A%28%5Cp%7BL%7D%29%5Cp%7BL%7D*%7C%24%29&i=DEL%20REY%20name%20CLUB&r=%241).

Comment: See my first comment above. I am using:  Dim results As String = Regex.Replace(text, "\P{L}*(?:(\p{L})\p{L}*|$)", "$1"). It works perfectly...thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The code here is an very simple answer that is adequate for my application (not as robust as that provided by Wiktor Stribizew). My input string is always upper case letters only because I force that with an If Not statement...see original question. The code:   Dim initials As String = Regex.Replace(myString, "(\B[A-Z][ ]*)", "")